# Choose the correct NoSQL database for my application

Tags: nosql, cassandra

My application will have hundreds reads and writes per second. Both of them have the same importance. Reads are typical `SELECT FROM WHERE`, but in `WHERE` I have three conditions. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE ((name1 between a AND b) AND (name2 BETWEEN c AND d) AND (name3 < e))
```

I have tried with Cassandra but is difficult planing a query with three conditions, and writes are faster than reads. Is there a NoSQL database that solves this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Answer this questions and consult [this](http://www.thoughtworks.com/articles/nosql-comparison) [pages](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis):

- **What is your data?**
- NoSQL is all the craze but **Why not use SQL?**

Answer (score 1):

NoSQL way of handling data is differs from relation way of thinking.

[Eventual consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) and [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) concepts are often used with NoSQL solutions.

So you probably should consider duplicating your data to be able to do such kind of reads.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. I would not rule out SQL databases just because NoSQL is considered super cool at the moment. You should give us more background information of what you are really trying to do. Depending on your requirements an in-memory database could be an option.